# SIGKILL init(PID=1) without sudo? Bug in linux?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I tried to run the following command `kill -9 1` and it says `bash: kill: (1) - Operation not permitted`.

It was pretty obvious to me that you should not be able to signal the init process without sudo.

But while writing the code for c-shell i encountered a bug(i think it really is). I compiled the following program and ran it. Now it has confused me and all my OS concepts.

```
#include <signal.h>
int main()
{
    killpg(1,9);
    return (0);
}
```

> Please save all your programs and run the code yourself.

Can anyone give me a reason and clarify my confusion.

**UPDATE**
Man page of `killpg()` read as...

> On Linux, killpg() is implemented as a library function that makes the
>   call kill(-pgrp, sig).

Man page of `kill()` read as...

> A PID of -1 is special; it indicates all processes except the kill
>   process itself and init.

Now the question is, what is the use of such a call that literally kills everything. It has many many dangerous applications rather than useful ones. But still since it has been kept in the linux kernel since so many years then it must have its own usefulness. But i can't figure out any. Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: `If pgrp is 0, killpg() sends the signal to the calling process's
       process group.  (POSIX says: If pgrp is less than or equal to 1, the
       behavior is undefined.`

Comment: i missed that line on the man page. This reminds me that i should read man pages twice before concluding anything. :)

Comment: You do not test around as root, don't you?

Comment: No, absolutely not. I even ran it on a virtual machine and it kill every process and also logs out the current user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Linux manual page for `killpg`:

> On Linux, `killpg()` is implemented as a library function that makes the call `kill(-pgrp, sig)`.

From the Linux manual page for `kill`:

> If `pid` equals -1, then `sig` is sent to every process for which the calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1 (init)

So you're running into a special case, where `killpg(1, 9)` doesn't in fact mean to send `SIGKILL` to pgrp 1, but instead it sends `SIGKILL` to everything it has permission to, due to a quirk of implementation. As others have pointed out, POSIX doesn't specify the behavior of `killpg` when its first argument is 1, so this is arguably not a bug.

Comment: but would not it be better if you just cross-check before sending the signal. This would prevent the system to suffer, as running the code logs out the user account.

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya Who is "you"?

Comment: by "you" i mean the actual code for the system call `kill`. What i mean is if we verify in the code itself and do not permit the signalling if PID==1, then this would prevent system crash.

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya there is no system crash, and the syscall is doing nothing wrong. The `kill` syscall doesn't get pid==1, it gets pid==-1, and it does exactly what it's documented to do in that case. `killpg` also does exactly what *it's* documented to do, and while what it does is mildly questionable, it's compatible with POSIX.

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya Please don't do that. If you have a new question, post a new question. Although in this case I don't believe your followup question is good material for SO.

Comment: Sorry,  my question may sound very naive but what does 'SO' stand for. You mentioned in the last comment

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya StackOverflow.

Comment: only those who have sound knowledge of linux kernel and sys calls can answer my new question. So i thought this would be a good place to get it answered. But if it still is not a good material for `SO` then i would make the necessary changes. suggest

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya But as people are saying, kill(-1); doesn't kill everything. It only kills stuff you have permission to kill. Now, of course if you are the root user and run that code, it will kill everything except the init process and the calling process. But if you're root, you can do anything anyway, so it's not more dangerous than other things you can do as root. It's just a quick way to get rid of everything, and perhaps start over without actually rebooting

Comment: @nos No, but the point is i ran it as a normal user. I even ran it on a virtual machine and it kill every process and also logs out the current user. Now, think of a situation where i give you the program and you run it on your system then it can kill every running process and put you in a bad situation. Now this is not expected at all. My idea is handing over such power(to kill every permissible process, which includes almost every running application, and even the login session) to any ordinary process is not justified.

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya your idea is incompatible with Unix.

Comment: @PinkeshBadjatiya What you describe isn't happening anywhere I have tried so far. Only the users own processes gets killed. Not everything. Sure, you'll get logged out, as most of the GUI stuff is running as your user and gets killed. I can give you a program that does far, far worse things than just kill processes. I don't think this is a bad feature at all, but quite handy for wiping out all processes for a user. So we can agree to disagree on that.

Answer (score 3):

From the man page:

> (POSIX says: If pgrp is less than or equal to 1, the behaviour is undefined.)

So you can't depend on any specific behavior if you do this.